# Lazy loading the has_and_belongs_to_many field while using mongoid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have the following models:

```
class Foo
 has_and_belongs_to_many :bars
end

class Bar
 has_and_belongs_to_many :foos
end
```

Each document representing the `Foo` instance has an array field called `bar_ids`. When ever a Foo object is retrieved from the DB, Mongoid retrieves the contents of the `bar_ids` also. When the document has 1000s of ids this can cause performance issues, i.e.

```
> Foo.first
#<Foo _id: 4fed60aa2bdf061c2c000001, bar_ids: [1, 2, 3.... 5000]>
```

In most cases I don't need to load the `bar_ids`. Is there way I can instruct the model to lazy load the `bar_ids`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question in the `mongoid` group and got an [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/J4pZcbofq9Y).  Essentially, one need to read the documentation of three gems to understand `mongoid 3` ( mongoid, moped, and origin).

Here is the relevant documentation [section](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html) of `origin` gem. The `without` or `only` clause can be used to filter the resulting document structure.

Loading selectively:

```
Foo.without(:bar_ids).first
```

Reloading selectively:

```
def reload_fields(*fields)
  return self if fields.empty? or new_record?
  # unscope and prevent loading from indentity map
  fresh = Mongoid.unit_of_work(disable: :current) do
    self.class.unscoped.only(*fields).find(id)
  end
  fields.each do |attr| 
    write_attribute(attr, fresh.read_attribute(attr))
    remove_change(attr) # unset the dirty flag for the reloaded field
  end
  self
end
```